# Load a variable on many pages without repeating myself

Tags: python, django

In Django, I have a sidebar navigation menu that has its own include file (let's call it sidebar.html). In sidebar.html, I *sometimes* load a special menu, depending on which page I am visiting. This special menu is generated from a database, so I need to run something like this in my views:

```
menu = Menu.objects.all()
```

Then I need to pass this variable to the template. However, there are some 30 pages where I need this menu. It seems like a repetitive solution to have the aforementioned line repeated 30 times in my views file. Is there a better way of doing it?

I only need the menu variable in sidebar.html, so there is only 1 file where I need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to go is to create a context processor (which adds items to contexts of all your requests) to add your menu to the context.

e.g.

```
c = RequestContext(request, {
    'menu': Menu.objects.all()
})
```

Then add it to `context_processors` in your `settings.py`

After doing that all templates will receive `menu` in their context, without writing it in every view.

You can learn more about django context processors [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/api/#django.template.RequestContext)

Comment: Great, thanks so much, exactly what I was looking for!